# Try_files for php causing error on fastcgi-php.conf, "try_files" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf:5

Tags: php, nginx

I tried to add try_files to check if php file exist, but it give me error.

```
"try_files" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf:5
```

Here the location I want to add try_files

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm-user.sock;
}
```

Here's my compete server block.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}



server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate /home/user/ssl/example.com.ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/user/ssl/example.com.key;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}



server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    root /home/user/public_html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name example.com;
    ssl_certificate /home/user/ssl/example.com.ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/user/ssl/example.com.key;

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    include /home/user/public_html/nginx.conf;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ^~ /wp-login.php {
        auth_basic "Administrator Login";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm-user.sock;
    }

    location /phpmyadmin {
        auth_basic "Restricted Content";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }

    # Phpmyadmin Configurations
    location /phpmyadmin {
        root /home/user/public_html/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        auth_basic "Restricted Content";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
        location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            root /home/user/public_html/;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm-user.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
        location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
            root /home/user/public_html/;
        }
    }

    location /phpMyAdmin {
        rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm-user.sock;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }

}
```

What's wrong with my server block? Why try_files gives me error? Is it fastcgi-php.conf bug? my Nginx version is 1.12.1

Another question, please check on my phpmyadmin block, i get it from here https://serverfault.com/questions/433785/nginx-phpmyadmin-redirecting-to-instead-of-phpmyadmin-upon-login
this format works, but as far as I know, root is not supposed to have trailing slash.

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

Remove `try_files` from this block

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm-user.sock;
}
```

You already have that in the `snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;` which is causing duplicate error

Comment: I see, but why I can't use `try_files $uri =403;` too? I can't even use different `try_files` if I'm using `snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;` EDIT: My bad, can't use more than 1 `try_files` on a single location. I'm so tired right now :D How about my 2nd question about phpmyadmin root using trailing slash?

Comment: @somuch72, try to keep one question in a post. So it is easier to comment and post solution

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue,
As the error says there is duplicated of common configuration, which nginx does not like it. Everything you need is just going to

```
/etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf:[line5]
```

and add an "#" at the beginning of the line, you may need to change some more lines on this file also regarding your nginx configuration

Comment: While that would stop the error status - it would also have the undesired effect of stopping PHP being parsed.